# Data Access from single table in sql server 2005 is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, query-optimization

Following is the script of table. Accessing data from this table is too slow.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Emails](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [datecreated] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Emails_datecreated]  
        DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UID] [nvarchar](250) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [From] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [To] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [Body] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [HTML] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [AttachmentCount] [int] NULL,
    [Dated] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Following query takes 50 seconds to fetch data.

```
select id, datecreated, UID, [From], [To], Subject, AttachmentCount, 
    Dated from emails
```

If I include **Body** and **Html** in select then time is event worse.

indexes are on:

- id   unique clustered
- From     Non unique non clustered
- To   Non unique non clustered

Tabls has currently 180000+ records.

There might be 100,000 records each month so this will become more slow as time will pass.

Does splitting data into two table will solve the problem?
What other indexes should be there?

Comment: Wait a minute:  it takes 50 seconds to retrieve 180K records?  Why are you retrieving 180K records?  What do you do with them?  Why is 50 seconds to long?  It's not like a human can process 180K records on the screen.  So my question is do you really need all the records, or is there a WHERE clause you omitted from your example?

Comment: I don't think indexes will work, since you don't have a where-clause. You're doing a full table scan, no matter what.

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve all the records from table?
Can't you use some restrcitive clause?

Comment: You are right that I have skipped where clause because I think that it should take 5 to 6 seconds to fetch these records. Why 5 to 6 seconds, because when I fetch only on 'id' it just take 2 seconds so this difference is too much.

Comment: Think. GETTING ALl records is a lot of IO - it does not take 5-6 seconds. A where clause is absolutely critical - nail down your data reqiest to only exactly what you need this moment. A fetch by ID should take VERY little time. a hundreth of a second or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly the volume of the data that's causing a problem. Because of this, you should not fetch the `Subject` column until you are need it. Even fetching `SUBSTRING(Subject, 100)` may be noticeably faster.

This may be irrelevant, but older versions of SQL Server suffered if the BLOB columns weren't the last in the row, so just as an experiment I'd move `[AttachmentCount]` and `[Dated]` above the three `nvarchar(max)` columns.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will go through SQL docs to verify your comments about BLOB.